# Obtaining impulse response by means of cross-correlation between input and output

Tags: noise, cross-correlation, correlation

Having a system with an input (sound emitter) that is defined as a unit-variance white noise sequence, and I get the output (sound receiver) so I can measure cross-correlation functions between them, how could I employ the correlation function to obtain the impulse response `h[n]`, which defines the media?

Comment: See [this answer of mine](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/44085/235) for the method that can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can calculate it!

define $y=h*t$, $r_{xy} -$
is the cross correlation

$r_{xy}(\tau)=\int_{-\infty}^ \infty x(t)y(\tau+t)dt = (y*x^-)(\tau) = (x^-*h*x)(\tau) =(r_{xx}*h)(\tau)\underbrace{=}_{r_{xx}=\delta}h(\tau)$

so actually the cross correlation is the impulse response

Comment: you are very welcome :)